# Scheme: Making a list of sublist maxes

Tags: list, scheme, max, sublist

Given a list, each item of which is an (r g b) color, return a list consisting of the
maximum component in each color.

Example: given ((123 200 6) (10 30 20) (212 255 10) (0 0 39) (37 34 34)), 
code should return (200 30 255 39 37)

Comment: Also, it should use filter, map, or accumulate to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (sublist-max list-of-lists)
    (map (lambda (sublist) (apply max sublist)) list-of-lists))
```